# External SSD drive(s) in USB enclosures are not being recognized by Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, sata

I have two external SSD drives that Disk Utility Mac OS X on my 2014 MacBook Pro doesn’t see at all. The laptop basically gives zero indication that something has been plugged in.

I’m connecting the drives to the laptop through a USB-to-SATA drive enclosure.

The drives are recognized and work on a PC. Also, connecting non-SSD 3.5” drives to the laptop via the same external enclosures works just fine. It’s just these SSD drives that aren’t seen by the laptop.

The SSD drives are:

1. 512GB Samsung 840 Pro
2. 256GB Crucial m4 SSD

The two enclosures that I'm using to connect them to the laptop:

1. [Sabrent USB 3.0 to SATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IKC14OG)
2. An older iROCKS SATA enclosure

Here’s what I've tried:

1. Plugging the drives into a PC works.
2. Putting non-SSD SATA II drives into the drive enclosure(s) works fine. They show up in “Disk Utility” and I can access them.
3. I’ve tried both USB ports on the laptop.
4. Rebooting (duh).

Since I can't *see* the drives in “Disk Utility” (or with `diskutil list` in Terminal), I doubt this is an issue of whether the drives are formatted or not.

Any ideas why the laptop is recognizing other drives but not these ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The problem was that the SSD drives were both encrypted with Bitlocker (from being used in Windows 8.1).

I still don't know why this made the entire drive(s) invisible to OSX. I could understand if the Bitlockered *partitions* didn't show up, but the fact that you can't even access a Bitlocker-encrypted *drive* to format it from within OSX is weird.

In any case, I fixed it by booting into Ubuntu on a PC with the SSD drives attached via external enclosures, then quick-formatting them. After that, I could plug them into the OSX laptop and it'd see the drives.